# Check if Screen Exists from Java App

Tags: java, screen

Can I check if a screen exists with a specific name from a java app? I'm using this:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        proc = run.exec("screen -S bungee -Q select . ; echo $?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    try {
        while(br.ready()){
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it prints: "-X: select: no or one argument required"
If I run *screen -S bungee -Q select . ; echo $?* directly from console it works...
Is there any way to do this?